# Wrong PDF Cyrillic encoding

Tags: pdf, encoding, copy-paste

Somewhen in the past we made this catalogue for a fans which we are offering.

It appears in a perfect cyrillic when I open it as a PDF.

But when I try to copy/paste text from it, this is what appears:

> Ã‚Ã¥Ã­Ã²Ã¨Ã«Ã Ã²Ã®Ã°Ã¨Ã²Ã¥ Ã±Ã  Ã¬Ã Ã¸Ã¨Ã­Ã¨ Ã±Ã«Ã³Ã¦Ã¥Ã¹Ã¨ Ã§Ã 
>   Ã²Ã°Ã Ã­Ã±Ã¯Ã®Ã°Ã²Ã¨Ã°Ã Ã­Ã¥ Ã­Ã  Ã£Ã Ã§Ã®Ã¢Ã¥ Ã¨ Ã£Ã Ã§Ã®Ã¢Ã¨
>   Ã±Ã¬Ã¥Ã±Ã¨. ÃˆÃ§Ã¯Ã®Ã«Ã§Ã¢Ã Ã² Ã±Ã¥ Ã§Ã  Ã¢Ã¥Ã­Ã²Ã¨Ã«Ã Ã¶Ã¨Ã¿ Ã­Ã 
>   Ã¡Ã¨Ã²Ã®Ã¢Ã¨ , Ã¯Ã°Ã®Ã¨Ã§Ã¢Ã®Ã¤Ã±Ã²Ã¢Ã¥Ã­Ã¨ Ã¨ Ã¤Ã°Ã³Ã£Ã¨
>   Ã¯Ã®Ã¬Ã¥Ã¹Ã¥Ã­Ã¨Ã¿. ÃÃ Ã¬Ã¨Ã°Ã Ã² Ã¯Ã°Ã¨Ã«Ã®Ã¦Ã¥Ã­Ã¨Ã¥ Ã¢
>   ÃµÃ«Ã Ã¤Ã¨Ã«Ã­Ã Ã²Ã  Ã¨ Ã±Ã³Ã¸Ã¨Ã«Ã­Ã  Ã²Ã¥ÃµÃ­Ã¨ÃªÃ  .
>   Ã’Ã°Ã Ã­Ã±Ã¯Ã®Ã°Ã²Ã¨Ã°Ã Ã² Ã§ÃºÃ°Ã­Ã¥Ã±Ã²Ã¨

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[This is the pdf files in Bulgarian](https://www.eldvigateli.com/images/pdf/%D0%91%D1%8A%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8.pdf)

Comment: When I copy & paste from it using Adobe Reader, I get the visible content. E.g. the title page extracts as *"ЕЛИН ИНЖЕНЕРИНГ
www.eldvigateli.com
ВЕНТИЛАТОРИ
ПЛОВДИВ: 4141 Трилистник,
Индустриален път №1
Тел: 031 499 188
GSM: 0895 581 912
Email: elin@eldvigateli.com"* - have you probably meanwhile fixed the issue and updated the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

I examined your sample file. The issue is in HebarU font. Cyrillic glyphs in this font are placed in the wrong positions, so if you copied them to the clipboard, you will get extended Latin characters.

There are a few ways to resolve this issue:

- replace the font in PDF doc;
- replace the font in the source file and render new PDF doc;
- try to decode with https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=bg
- copy text to Notepad and fix encoding;

Here is a snippet on C#:

```
public static void FixCyrillicText()
{
    var sourceText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\aspose\demodata.txt");
    var sourceChars = sourceText.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceChars.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((sourceChars[i] > 127) && (sourceChars[i] < 256)) 
                                       sourceChars[i] += (char)848;   
    }            
    var fixedText = new String(sourceChars);
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\aspose\demodata-fix.txt", fixedText);
}
```